# Seed db with a particular record set with associated records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a feature where when a person signs up for an account we will automatically populate their account with default categories and items to get them started.

Further, they can optionally purchase additional category sets to add/populate their accounts at anytime.

I am thinking my choices are:

1) Somehow use seeds.rb
2) Store these records in a YAML file and load in upon account creation
3) Store these records in the DB as a default set and clone/dup them.

Any help appreciated w/ code examples to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:
Have a flag in the DB to identify `first_sign_in` Store the data in a `yaml` file (e.g `db/users.yml`) and do:

```
def populate_user
  user.update_attributes(YAML.load(Rails.root + 'db/users.yml')) if first_sign_in == 0
end
```

Then you can add this to an `after_create` hook so it is called only when a `user` is created

Comment: How would I handle associated records in the YAML file?  In detail I'm creating categories w/ certain items associated to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it differently.  I'd have a "Registration" form object between the controller and model(s).  Have this build some default categories and items at the same time as it first builds a user.  How you isolate the attributes of those default items depends on how complex they are.  If they're simple a default hash in the form object will suffice, if they're complex you can pull in from YML.

When I've done this in the past - had a signup which requires multiple object creation I've had a `RegistrationsController`, a `RegistrationForm` object which takes the params and validates everything, and is also responsible for knowing what to save, and sometimes in intermediate `Registrar` object (Struct usually) which has all the logic for callbacks.  The `registrations_controller` initializes a `registrar` which is sent a message `register(registration_form)`.

This leads to isolation of responsibilities and much cleaner code in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided are definite options, with which I experimented with.  However, I decided to go a different route.  I realized that I would need to manage these 'template' records and a DB would be easiest.

1) I setup a column on the table 'is_template' to mark the records that will be used to seed other accounts.

2) Created an `after_create` call back to seed the accounts using these records.

3) To make matters easier I used the [amoeba gem](https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba) which allows me to copy the records and their associated records which works great since some of them have `has_many` relationships.

This has been working great so far - and I also have a way for myself and the non-tech staff to update the records.